# Keyboard's "g" key not working

Tags: keyboard, hardware

My keyboard's "G" button has stopped working all of a sudden.

I didn't make any update or any hardware change. I have to use on screen keyboard to type "G" alphabet.

Checked on BIOS, still not working, probably hardware problem.

Do I need to change whole keyboard or specific key can be changed?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the g still work while the keyboard is connected to another computer? Or if you have windows as well in Windows? It is unlikely for a single key to stop working.

Comment: welcome to askubuntu, try the keyboard with other machine, OS, you probably have a hardware issue

Comment: Thank you guys for advice but it is laptop keyboard and seems to me a hardware problem, because it not even working on BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is not a hardware problem, try checking with another keyboard or reboot and enter bios setup and test key by setting a password for bios, if key is not working try cleaning it, something may be lodged under it.
If the key is "just blocked" in Ubuntu please let me know the details of the system > preference > keyboard [Layouts Tab].

Comment: It is not working on bios too that means it is in hardware. And it is a laptop keyboard so can't be checked on other machines. Layout is English US qwerty.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone issue hardware key problem on laptop:
I have hardware problem with my q, Q key on my laptop
I have ubuntu-mate 19.10

```
gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us  
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

there in pc file, there is only one LSGT key, I took from us file { [q, Q] } definition and replaced it in pc.

After that

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

logout/login
Universal Access/Onboard now shows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue with <kbd>g</kbd> and <kbd>h</kbd> keys not working. What worked for me is:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```